# What is the proper terminology for the parts of a bayesian hierarchial model?

Tags: terminology, hierarchical-bayesian

Lets say I have the following JAGS model, what are the proper terms for the three parts and 1/tau?

```
  model{
  #Term???
  for(n in 1:Ndata){
  y[n] ~ dnorm( mu[ subj[n] ], tau[ subj[n]] )
  }

  #Term???
  for(s in 1:Nsubj){
  mu[s] ~ dnorm( muG, tauG) 
  tau[s] ~ dgamma( 5, 5)
  }

  #Term???
  muG ~ dnorm( 80, .01) 
  tauG ~ dgamma( 1, 1)

  }
```

What would I call each of the three parts?

Also, for the parameters I would say:

- mu= "Individual Level Mean"
- tau= "Individual Level Precision"
- muG= "Group Level Mean"
- tauG= "Group Level Precision"

Now what would I call 1/tau? "Variance"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see slide 12 of the following document:

http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~rsteorts/jags_present.pdf

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that it seems confusing to refer to the "error" of the fit as variance since variance is usually a property of the data.

Comment: @Flask The variance is a general definition that applies to distributions in general. For the normal model this quantity happens to be $\sigma^2$. The variance of a data set is an estimator of the distribution where they come from. This [link](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~fdominic/teaching/bio656/labs/labs08/lab2.popular.pdf) may shed some light on this.

Comment: I just realized this example is not perfect for what I am thinking. If instead I was fitting a line and modelling the error of the fit as normally distributed it would be analogous to the mean squared error. You would say still use the term "variance" and if I report the square root it would be "standard deviation"?

Comment: @Flask I see your point. Indeed, if you have a linear regression model of the type ${\bf y} = {\bf X}{\bf \beta} + {\bf \varepsilon}$, where each entry $\varepsilon_j\stackrel{ind.}{\sim} \text{Normal}(0,\tau^{-1}= \sigma^2)$, then ${\bf \varepsilon}$ represents the residual errors, which is a random vector, $\tau$ is the precision of the entries of this random vector, $\sigma^2$ is the variance, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

Comment: @Multis So... if I were to discuss in a publication perhaps I could say "residual error variance" and people would understand. Because there would also be a variance term for e.g. the slope parameter.

Comment: @Flask In a publication you can simply refer to $\sigma$ as a parameter of the Bayesian model. "We use the prior $\pi()$ for $\sigma$", "the posterior distribution of $\sigma$ is given by", "the posterior variance of $\sigma$", "the posterior variance of $\beta$" ... Things like that. In Bayesian linear regression $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are random variables, and therefore they are better described through their posterior distributions, rather than just their variances.

Comment: I understand but need to explain plots to people who do not know what a posterior distribution is and will glaze over if too many alien symbols are used.